# Jsoup scraping google results and get website link from button on the right side

Tags: java, jsoup

Currently I have made this function.

```
private static void getAllLinks(String URL) {
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Chrome").ignoreHttpErrors(true).get();

        Elements links = doc.select("div._mdf._ykh.kno-fb-ctx3 > a");
        print("\nLinks: (%d)", links.size());
        for (Element link : links) {
             print("%s", link.attr("abs:href"));
            mainLinks.add(link.attr("abs:href"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and the link of the page is https://www.google.com/search?q=Ajo+Calvary+Baptist+Church.

[image: see Image]

Comment: Found the solution. The links where being populated after a script was being executed but jsoup got the page before the script fully executed. So instead tried HTMLUNIT that works like a mini browser and executes all scripts before getting the HTML from page. Code is given below.

Comment: `try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
         final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.google.com/search?q=Ajo+Calvary+Baptist+Church");
         
         HtmlAnchor el = (HtmlAnchor) page.getByXPath("//a[@class='ab_button']").get(0);
         System.out.println(el.getAttribute("href"));
     } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } `

Comment: Then post it as an answer and accept it, so people will be able to use your solution.

Comment: @TDG sorry I'm new to stack overflow. I thought I couldn't post an answer to my own question so add the code in the comments. Thank you for letting me know that.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution see the comments above for the explanation. You need [HTMLUNIT](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) instead of Jsoup for this.

```
    try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.google.com/search?q=Ajo+Calva‌​ry+Baptist+Church");
        HtmlAnchor el = (HtmlAnchor) page.getByXPath("//a[@class='ab_button']").get(0);
        System.out.println(el.getAttribute("href"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```